# Service Fabric expose same port on different nodes

Tags: azure-service-fabric

I have a Service Fabric cluster with 2 nodes.
Each node is exposed to the web with a stateless Asp.net Core 2.0 service.
I'm using **HttpSys**.

Each node has a unique IP address and the following ports:

**First service on Node 1:**

```
 <Endpoint Protocol="http" Name="ServiceEndpoint" Type="Input" Port="80" />
 <Endpoint Protocol="http" Name="ServiceEndpointSecure" Type="Input" Port="443" />
```

**Second service on Node 2**

```
 <Endpoint Protocol="http" Name="ServiceEndpoint" Type="Input" Port="81" />
 <Endpoint Protocol="http" Name="ServiceEndpointSecure" Type="Input" Port="444" />
```

I would like both services to listen to port 80 and 443 but If I change the ServiceManifest I see the error that the port is in use.

How can I make this work being the services on two different nodes with two different IPs and two different DNS names associated to the IPs?

Answer (score 0):

Use a load balancer like [Azure Load Balancer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/load-balancer/load-balancer-overview) to forward the traffic to the 2 ip addresses to your individual services. They can run at any port inside the cluster.

Alternative: Azure [API management.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-api-management-overview) can also be used to create rules that direct traffic to specific services.